# Assigning captions to dynamic form controls buttons based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba, caption

I am pretty new to Excel VBA so I apologize in advance if something will be vaguely described.
I am having a code, which inserts on the "Demand Overview" worksheet into column W certain number of product names ("Product X", "Product Y" etc....the number of products are dynamically changing from 1 to 100), always starting in the cell W2 and always skipping one cell between each product (like Product X would be in W2, Product Y in W4 etc.)
What I would like to code in VBA, is to create a form control button for each of the product names and to change their caption to the name of the products in column W.
I could write the code for dynamically creating as many form control buttons as many product names are in column W, however, I am struggling to assign the captions to them, since I always get the error: "Unable to get the Buttons property of the Worksheet class"

The assigning logic would be that Button 1 would get the product name located in W2, Button 2 would get the product name located in W4 etc.

Any help would be highly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

```
Sub AddInfo()


Dim butn As Button
Dim rng As Range
Dim trial As Range
Dim i As Integer

Sheets("Demand Overview").Select
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("S:S")
For Each trial In ActiveSheet.Range("W:W")

 If trial.Value <> "" Then Set butn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(rng.Left, 
 trial.Top, 150, 26)

Next trial

'the code works until this point

With ActiveSheet
For i = 1 To 100
.Buttons("Button" & i).Caption = Range("W" & 2 * i)
 Next i
 End With

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Think it makes more sense to reference the button as you create it so you know you are referencing the correct one.

```
Sub AddInfo()

Dim butn As Button
Dim rng As Range
Dim trial As Range
Dim i As Long

With Sheets("Demand Overview")
    Set rng = .Range("S:S")
    For Each trial In .Range("W:W")
        If trial.Value <> "" Then
            Set butn = .Buttons.Add(rng.Left, trial.Top, 150, 26)
            i = i + 1
            butn.Caption = .Range("W" & 2 * i).Value
        End If
    Next trial
End With

End Sub
```

By the way, I wouldn't loop through the whole of W, find the last row and limit your loop to what is necessary rather than all million rows.